# Marca de Agua en TextBox con C#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando poner una marca de agua en los textbox. La idea es que al iniciar la aplicación, se vea en cada textbox un mensaje. El problema es que cuando inicio la app no los muestra, solo los muestra una vez que salí de esa caja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esas cajas debería salir, al momento de correr la app, el/los mensaje/s: Ingrese Usuario /Ingrese Contraseña y es no es así. 
Si presiono la tecla tabulación o con el mouse cambio de textbox si sale el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
public Providus(){
            InitializeComponent();
            txtUsuario.MaxLength = 20;
            txtContrasena.PasswordChar = '*';
            txtContrasena.MaxLength = 16;
            txtUsuario.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
            txtContrasena.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
            this.txtUsuario.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txtUsuario_SinTexto);
            this.txtContrasena.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txtContrasena_SinTexto);
            this.txtContrasena.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.txtContrasena_BorradoDeMarca);
            this.txtUsuario.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.txtUsuario_BorradoDeMarca);
        }
```

Y este es el método para cada uno:

```
private void txtUsuario_SinTexto(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (txtUsuario.Text.Length == 0 || txtUsuario.Text=="" || txtUsuario.Text==null) {
                txtUsuario.Text = "Ingrese usuario";
                txtUsuario.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
            }
        }

        private void txtUsuario_BorradoDeMarca(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (txtUsuario.Text == "Ingrese usuario"){
                txtUsuario.Text = "";
                txtUsuario.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            }
        }
```

Comment: es mas facil que uses los eventos de los propios texbox, sino mal recuerdo los eventos que se usan para eso en Enter y Leave

Comment: ESto es wpf o winforms? Si usas el evento leave, para hacerlo manual, se va a mostrar solo cuando salgas... el comportamiento en este caso es correcto

Comment: Entiendo, ¿Y cómo hago para que muestre un texto cuando inicie la app?

Comment: Tendrias que ponerlo en el LOAD de tu form para que cuando inicie lo agregue dale doble clic sobre tu form y entras al codigo

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no funcionó

Comment: Podrias mostrar como lo inetentaste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta que voy a brindar es una manera alternativa, y a mi parecer, mucho mejor que estar mezclando eventos como `Enter` o `Leave` dentro del *code-behind* del formulario.

La idea es derivar de la clase `TextBox` con el fin de encapsular la funcionalidad que quieres que los cuadros de texto posean. En este caso buscas que muestren una marca de agua (watermark).

Entonces, empezamos con la creación de un control personalizado llamado `WatermarkTextBox` (en VS basta con agregar un nuevo elemento y escoger la plantilla que dice "Custom Control"). Después de hecho esto, el código siguiente sirve para tener un textbox con marca de agua que incluso se puede configurar en tiempo de diseño.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string textoMarcaAgua = string.Empty;

    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Creamos una propiedad pública para poder setear el valor de la marca de agua en el diseñador de Windows Forms.
    public string TextoMarcaAgua
    {
        get => textoMarcaAgua;
        set
        {
            if (value != textoMarcaAgua)
            {
                textoMarcaAgua = value;
                ActualizarMarcaAgua();
            }
        }
    }

    //Sobreescribimos el método OnHandleCreated para inicializar la marca de agua.
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        ActualizarMarcaAgua();
    }

    private void ActualizarMarcaAgua()
    {
        if (IsHandleCreated) //Enviamos el mensaje solo si el handle del control ha sido creado
        {
            NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.EM_SETCUEBANNER, (IntPtr)1, TextoMarcaAgua);
        }
    }      
}
```

Notarás el uso de la clase `NativeMethods`. Se suele dar dicho nombre a la clase que contiene las llamadas al API de Windows (lo que se conoce como *Platform Invocation* o P/Invoke). A continuación la definición de dicha clase:

```
static class NativeMethods
{        
    internal const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
}
```

Todo lo anterior es posible porque Winforms no es más que un *wrapper* sobre el API de Windows. Para más información puedes revisar el siguiente enlace sobre la función [SendMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) y el mensaje [EM_SETCUEBANNER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esta ha sido la respuesta que estaba buscando. Te lo agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo veo es que no inicializas, me explico.

Tu codigo funciona, pero necesitas o bien entrar en los textbox o bien de entrada que tengan ya el valor preasignado, sino, estaran en blanco hasta que actues sobre ellos.

Haz una funcion para recorrer los textbox, ponerle el foco y sacarselo o sino, directamente al crear los textbox, le estableces la propiedad text a lo que tu quieres y ya arreglaste el problema